# How to wait for first function to complete before running second function javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a search facility for a website that sometimes takes a few seconds to load results, so I added a loading image to show while it is searching and disappear when it finishes.

```
    function search(category) {
        var loading = document.getElementById("#loading");
        loading.style.display = "block";
        var input = document.getElementById(category);
        var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
        console.log(filter);
        var catagory_values = document.getElementsByClassName(category);
        var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('search-row');

        for (i = 0; i < catagory_values.length; i++) {
            if (catagory_values[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
                nodes[i].style.display = "table-row";
            } else {
                nodes[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        loading.style.display = "none";

    }
```

The function above is actually for multiple search boxes, in the input it just uses `onkeyup` to call the function. The searching element of this works fine, but the loading image is not showing, if I comment out the line `loading.style.display = "none";` then it starts showing the image when I start typing, but doesn't go away, but with it their it doesn't show at all, I have been trying to find an answer for the last few days, but I haven't been able to, I have tried making separate functions and doing a callback, but nothing seems to work. Please test and let me know if you have a solution. Thanks

Comment: So you are doing an on page search and not connecting via ajax?

Comment: @imvain2  Thats correct

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `async promise`.

Below is an example, which uses async and then to wait for the function to complete, then run the then function.

```
<input class="input" type="text">


         var loading = document.getElementById("#loading");

         async function search(category) {
            loading.style.display = "block";
            var input = document.getElementById(category);
            var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
            console.log(filter);
            var catagory_values = document.getElementsByClassName(category);
            var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('search-row');

            for (i = 0; i < catagory_values.length; i++) {
                if (catagory_values[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
                    nodes[i].style.display = "table-row";
                } else {
                    nodes[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }


        }



        var _input = document.querySelector(".input");

_input.addEventListener("input",function(e){
   search(e.target.value).then(
          loading.style.display = "none"
    );
});
```

Comment: so what should be in the `search_string` part?

Comment: @gs I changed it, it is  `category` that you are passing.

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: category is not defined` in the console

Comment: @gs, since you never posted your keyup function, I didn't include that part in my code. Using my updated function and the call to the function, call it like you did before in your keyup, just pass it the value that you were using before.

Comment: I used `<input type="text" onkeyup="search('name')">` and I still have this, however I am still getting that error in the console

Comment: @gs I have updated my code to change your input so it doesn't have an inline onkeyup and added an event handler instead.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `defer` keyword in the script tag to run it after the other script is finished.

The defer attribute is only for external scripts.

refer to this for more detail: https://javascript.info/script-async-defer